# A question about a block of condition relate to && operator

Tags: c++, while-loop, conditional-statements

Excuse me, Allow me to ask, condition in While Loop below, What meaning? Please Explain to me explicitly, so I'm just beginner, Thanks you very much much

```
while (slow_p && fast_p && fast_p->next) 
    {
           
    
    statement
    
    }
```

Comment: The operator && is an alternative writing for the keyword `and`

Comment: Looks like the hare and tortoise algorithm

Comment: Itself, I thought that condition which is != NULL, but I don't certain

Answer (score 1):

The while loop will work until all three `slow_p`, `fast_p`, `next pointer of fast_p` are not **NULL**.

`statement` will be executed **continuously** if the above condition is **true**.

Comment: NOPE! The `while` loop works **while** all three pointers exist (are not NULL), not **until** they exist.

Comment: True is 1 and is !=NULL, False is 0 and NULL, Right?

Comment: @NagaiKei Yes, Right!